# Call to undefined relationship on model

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

We have the following class using $with:

```php
class CargaHorasEmpleado extends Model
{

    protected $table = "empleados_horas";
    protected $with = ["tipoTarea", "proyecto", "empleado", "empleadoQueHizoLaCarga"];

    public function tipoTarea()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\TipoTarea', 'id_tipo_tarea', 'id')->withTrashed();
    }

    public function empleado()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Empleado', 'id_empleado', 'id')->withTrashed();
    }

    public function empleadoQueHizoLaCarga()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Empleado', 'id_empleado_cargo_hs', 'id')->withTrashed();
    }

    public function proyecto()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Proyecto', 'id_proyecto', 'id')->withTrashed();
    }

}
```

This is the class TipoTarea

```php
 namespace App;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class TipoTarea extends Model
    {
        protected $table = 'tipos_tareas';

        public $timestamps = false;

        protected $fillable = [
            'titulo', 'descripcion'
        ];

    }
```

Thep page throws the error: "Call to undefined relationship [tipoTarea] on model [App\CargaHorasEmpleado]". That's the only relationship that's not working. The others are fine. What's wrong?

Comment: what are you calling that is causing that; a simple `CargaHorasEmpleado::find(...)`?

Comment: Here's the call:   $empleado->horasCargadas->where("fecha", '>=', $inicio)->where("fecha", '<=', $fin)->sortBy('fecha')->values()->all();    where "horasCargadas" is a relationship that gives a collection of CargaHorasEmpleado

Comment: do any of these other models in this chain also have `$with` set to load relationships?

Comment: No, and as I said above, all other relationships work fine (i.e. empleado, empleadoQueHizoLaCarga, proyecto)

Comment: Looks like there's a typo somewhere. Can you search your code for "`tiposTarea"?

Comment: Sorry I wrote it here instead of pasting it, the mistake was just here

Comment: You just tell the problem without telling us what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score -1):

Well, isn't the relationship called "tipoTarea"? You wrote "tiposTarea"

Comment: No, that was just a mispelling here, sorry. The problem is not that.

Comment: Hmm, you're missing the relationship on `tipoTarea` to `CargaHorasEmpleado`

Comment: can you explain?

Comment: Yes, you're saying that `tipoTarea` belongs to `CargaHorasEmpleado` Model, but you're not defining the inverse relationship on `TipoTarea`, example:

`public function cargaHorasEmpleado()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\TipoTarea', 'id_tipo_tarea')->withTrashed();
    }`

Answer (score -1):

The problem was that my class "TipoTarea" didn't use softdeletes. So the error was in using the "WithTrashed" method. The correct way is:

```
  public function tipoTarea()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\TipoTarea', 'id_tipo_tarea', 'id');
    }
```